# Is it possible to invert pyplot figures to the corresponding code?

Tags: matplotlib

Is there any tool that can receive an input of a pyplot figure (in .png format), and output its corresponding data and code? I'm working on an earlier project which I want to change the figure but I can't find the original pyplot code to generate the figures.

Really appreciate if someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this. You can however extract the data using a tool like [webplotdigitizer](https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/) - I think that's probably your best bet.